# Does GeForce 710 GT support three displays support? How to? Practice

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

Recently our company decided to order GeForce 710GT in order to support three displays for multiple PCs. But practically it doesn't work at all. The third display is not recognized by OS and NVidia driver. I am about to exchange it or even make a return.
Please advise anything useful regarding this matter. The driver is recent one. Windows 10.
[image: Not active cooling system that was delivered]

Comment: It's important to note that a graphics card doesn't always support all of it's ports in use at the same time (sometimes its just for compatibility it has more than one type - vga/dvi/hdmi/dp - it might have 3 but only support 2 at any time). The 710GT is such a cheap / low spec card.

Comment: @Smock 3 , noted. I believe it works because I am using adapter that is not helpful at all. Trying different models of monitors. Still nothing.

Comment: Is that the instructions I see on the desk under the card? Is there any spec info about how many it supports on there? Have you got the manufacturer / model/serial no. of the particular 710GT you have? Might be able to look up the specs online somewhere...

Comment: The [specifications](http://www.galax.com/en/graphics-card/700-series/galax-geforce-gt-710-2gb.html) say that card supports 3 monitors. Does each monitor work on its own with the card, instead of trying 3 at once?

Comment: @Andrew Morton , you are correct about the reference on the specification. Everything is connected according to requirements. Nothing more above this. And thanks for your reply, sir.

Comment: The DVI connector has 3 different versions... It can be DVI-A and only analogue part is used. Other is DVI-D, which uses only digital lines. The last one is DVI-I which supports both analogue and digital. Now depends what supports graphic card, display and cable. DVI-A and DVI-D are not compatible with each other since different lines are used.

Comment: From experience most graphics cards only support 3 monitors when at least one of those monitors is DisplayPort

Answer (score 0):

My answer regarding this matter is just usage of the correct cables. HDMI for HDMI, VGA for itself and DVI (the most a s s). DVI must be splitted pins + 1 plain. Adapters for DVI don't work as I have tried.
By the way, I am satisfied with GeForce GT 710 GT.
Thanks for your attention, I hope it will be useful for someone.[image: Geforce 710 GT cabling]